# How to use a variable/list in a nested function that is imported

Tags: python-3.x, nested, global-variables

I have multiple functions that I intent to import that will be using a certain number of variables/lists in the main module.
The only issue is that I keep getting an error:

```
for lst in arr:
NameError: name 'arr' is not defined
```

My code is this:

```
#main code
#mine.py

import my_unique
import numpy as np
from numpy import asarray
from numpy import save, load

my_data = np.load('my_things.npz', allow_pickle=True )
moa = my_data['x']
def pay():
    global arr
    arr = np.array(list(def_moa))
    similies = my_unique.simily()
pay()

#my_unique.py

def simily():
    
    for lst in arr:
        exportable_model = bjw.build_exportable_model(lst)
        runtime_model = bjw.build_runtime_model(exportable_model)
#        more code...
```

Is there a way to male the 'arr' accessible to the 'simily' function?
Kindest regards

Comment: Pass it as a parameter to `simily`.

Comment: Thanks. This worked on python idle.!